# How do I detect scroll with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I scroll with this which works fine:

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $("body")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
```

But I would also to like to detect when I scroll the page myself.

I tried all of these:

```
$('window').on('scroll', function (e){
  console.log("scroll");
});

$('#historyScroll').on('scroll', function (e){
  console.log("scroll");
});

$('body').on('scroll', function (e){
  console.log("scroll");
});

$('document').on('scroll', function (e){
  console.log("scroll");
});

$('window').on({'scroll' : function (){
  console.log("scroll");
}});

$('#historyScroll').on({'scroll' : function (){
  console.log("scroll");
}});

$('body').on({'scroll' : function (){
  console.log("scroll");
}});
 $('document').on({'scroll' : function (){
  console.log("scroll");
}});


 $('window').on('scroll', function (){
  console.log("scroll");
});

  $('#historyScroll').on('scroll', function (){
  console.log("scroll");
});

 $('body').on('scroll', function (){
  console.log("scroll");
});

 $('document').on('scroll', function (){
  console.log("scroll");
});
```

But nothing gets logged. What can I do to figure out why it isn't working?

See also [demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgWfQ/).

Comment: Try using just `$(document).scroll(...)`.

Comment: `$(window).scroll(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the single quotes around `window` or `document` in your selector:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { ... });
// Or...
$(document).on('scroll', function() { ... });
```

Both `window` and `document` are default JavaScript objects. Using `$('window')`, for example, attempts to select a `<window>` element within your document.

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZP2v/)

You want to try

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  //code here
});
```

You tried:

```
$('document').on({'scroll' : function (){
  console.log("scroll");
}});
```

and was close, but you need to remove the `'` from the selector and the `{` and `:` from the scroll function.

Your version would make jQuery look for a HTML element called `<document>` (which doesn't exist). Same as `window`, you don't use `'` with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  //Whatever on scroll
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgWfQ/2/)**